# Free spin (Curie) Paramagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter

I'm working through a derivation for Curie paramagnetism and hope someone could help clarify a couple of steps. The way that makes sense to me (although now I have seen the wikipedia derivation below I realise this way is pretty long) is to not take any high temperature approximations until near the end of the derivation where I have:

$M=g_J\mu_B[(J+1/2)coth[g_J\mu_B\beta(J+1/2)]-\frac{1}{2}coth(g_J\mu_B\beta/2)]$

now to get to the curie susceptibility it seems that when taking the high T limit of the above expression the leading $\frac{1}{x}$ term of the coth expansion is ignored and the second $\frac{1}{3}x$ term is considered (this pops out the correct answer $\chi_{curie}=\frac{n(g_J\mu_B)^2}{3}\frac{J(J+1)}{k_BT}$). I can't find or think or any sensible reason for this apart from when we take the limit of zero B the infinity is just a constant which has no temperature dependence (which is what we're interested in) so we happily ignore it.

The wikipedia method below almost makes sense aside from the last equality where I can't follow how they've simplified the sums (I can see that you could drop the first parts of the sums as they have no H dependence so won't matter when it comes to finding $\chi_{curie}$ but this still doesn't seem to work)

$\bar{m}=\frac{\sum\limits_{M_{J}=-J}^{J}{M_{J}g_{J}\mu _{B}e^{{M_{J}g_{J}\mu _{B}H}/{k_{B}T}\;}}}{\sum\limits_{M_{J}=-J}^{J}{e^{{M_{J}g_{J}\mu _{B}H}/{k_{B}T}\;}}}\simeq g_{J}\mu _{B}\frac{\sum\limits_{M_{J}=-J}^{J}{M_{J}\left( 1+{M_{J}g_{J}\mu _{B}H}/{k_{B}T}\; \right)}}{\sum\limits_{M_{J}=-J}^{J}{\left( 1+{M_{J}g_{J}\mu _{B}H}/{k_{B}T}\; \right)}}=\frac{g_{J}^{2}\mu _{B}^{2}H}{k_{B}T}\frac{\sum\limits_{-J}^{J}{M_{J}^{2}}}{\sum\limits_{M_{J}=-J}^{J}{\left( 1 \right)}}$

(Copied from Wikipedia paramagnetism article)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your algebra.

Hints: 1) If you write the expansion of M(T) for large T (small $\beta$), you will find that the $1/\beta$ term in the first term cancels the one in the second term, so you have to go to the next order.

2) The sum $\sum_{i=-N}^{N} i = 0$, which you can tell by making the variable replacement $j = -i$.

Answer (score 0):

The first form of M is a Brillouin function which has and expansion that gives the correct answer, just have to justify this for myself